# How to make the NVD3 discreteBarChart labels on the X axis to adapt to the width or to the number of labels?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm currently using a the [NVD3 discreteBarChart](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/discreteBar.html) but I have a lot of data and the labels on the X axis, which are dates in my application, are encroaching upon each other like this : [image: picture below]). This doesn't happen with a [multiBar](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBar.html) or a [linePlusBar](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/linePlusBar.html) chart, where the labels are automatically adapted : [image]

How can I prevent the lablels on the discreteBar chart to impinge on the others?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Why not use a multibar with just one group?

Comment: You are right it was my second option and I will do that if I don't find the solution. In that case it would be great if I could hide the "Stacked" and "Grouped" radio buttons but I don't know how I could do that :/

Comment: Have you tried something like `chart.xAxis.ticks(10)`?

Comment: I just tried it but it doesn't change anything, even with different values...

Answer (score 0):

Little late to answer, but to get similar results but using multi-barchart as mentioned by [Lars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172002/lars-kotthoff) , you can use following command to get a similar graph (i.e hide "stacked" and "grouped", as well as legend buttons).

```
n1$chart(showControls = FALSE, showLegend = FALSE)
```